# ImportError when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've recently installed TensorFlow using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` then when I import it, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: whats your python version?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: Follow this closed TensorFlow issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23683

Comment: python version 3.7.3

Comment: @JammyDodger what dependencies should I install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
pip install setuptools
```

if wont change anything uninstall tensorflow and try (if you have conda env):

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Comment: Why would they install setuptools?

Comment: If your are wondering, google it or crate new post on stackoverflow about setuptools.

Comment: I'm not wondering. Setuptools is an inferior package installer. Installing setuptools will not fix the problem

Comment: got conda env? If yes, try second option form my answer.